# permission to record audio on iOS

Tags: ios, qt, qaudiorecorder

I am writing an app that records an audio file from the user. I noticed that when other apps that do something similar are installed, a window is displayed, warning the user that the app wants to access the microphone, and the user has to explicit give permission to the app to do so.

Does Qt have any API that tells iOS about the intention of the app to access certain devices, which would cause that warning window to be displayed?

Thanks!

Comment: @Cancellas,it is late but , there is new update for latest version of ios ( > 11) Have to add key - value into info.plist to access microphone. For more info : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38498275/ios-10-changes-in-asking-permissions-of-camera-microphone-and-photo-library-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You don't have to handle it manually**. `iOS` will automatically ask for permission if the user didn't accept it before.

The very first time your app will need microphone, an alert will be displayed. If the user allows it, he will never see the alert again. If he refuses, he will have to turn it `ON` manually in `iOS settings`. Nevertheless, there's maybe a way to handle a previous refusing in-app.

Comment: Thanks! It helped me  a lot!